# Swift 2: Call function from Gamescene.swift in AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a function called decideEnemy() in my GameScene.swift file. I'd like to call this function in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in my AppDelegate.swift file. Here's what I've tried but no luck:

```
var gscene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

And under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I call:

```
gscene!.decideEnemy()
```

I'm probably missing something easy but I've been unable to find how to get this to work. xCode doesn't give me any errors the function just doesn't fire. Any suggestions? Thanks!

So, I'm trying to run this in AppDelegate.swift because I've got the following in place:

```
var lastTime : NSDate!

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let defaultValues = ["lastTime" : NSDate()]
    defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)

    lastTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lastTime") as! NSDate

    elapsedTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(lastTime)

if elapsedTime > 30 {

        gscene!.decideEnemy()



    }


}
```

So the idea is I record "lastTime" when the game is closed. Then when the game opens if a certain amount of time has passed then I want to call my decideEnemy() function.

Should I instead call my "elapsedTime" into my GameScene.swift file and run that If statement under didMoveToView? How would I go about that?

So this is what I ended up doing. In my GameScene file I added:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

And then added this to ViewDidLoad:

```
if appDelegate.elapsedTime > 30 {

        decideEnemy()

    }
```

Comment: That app delegate method is executed well before any views are on screen. Your code is creating a new instance of the scene and executing the function but that scene will be discarded when `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` exits.  `didMoveToView` in your `GameScene` class may be more appropriate

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I should mention I'm trying to call this here because I've got something set up to compare the NSDate from when the app closes to when the app opens and if a certain amount of time has passed then I want it to call this function. Going to edit my original post to add that code.

Comment: Again, no reason that that code has to be in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.  If you do want to compare the date in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` then you can set a boolean property on your app delegate and check that later in `didMoveToView`.  Also your code, as written, won't do what you want since it always registers "now" via `registerDefaults` - this will overwrite any saved value.  What you want is to check if `objectForKey("lastTime")` is not nil

Comment: The timing part works. I've got additional code in applicationWillTerminate and applicationDidEnterBackground to save the "lastTime" default. I just got everything working. Your initial comment made me realize what I was doing wrong. Adding my code to my original post.